# Linear second order differential equation for 2D function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I know what the solution to the "2d particle in a box" wave equation is. But I'm having a hard time *getting* there. I have no idea how to solve the equation:

$$a(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x} \psi + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y} \psi) + c \psi = 0$$

For a typical second order linear differential equation, we'd have:

$$ay'' + by' + cy = 0 \rightarrow y(x) = e^{rx} : ar^2 + br + c = 0$$

But I can't seem to get to the solution for two variables. How do you solve such a differential equation?

Comment: You have the wrong equation. $c$ should be multiplied by $\psi$. The linear equation formula has a similar issue, $c$ should be replaced by $cy$.

Comment: @Andrei yes, my bad, a transciption error when copying it over to stack overflow. But the question still stands -- I couldn't figure out how to solve the (proper) diffeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problems we can try the separation of variables method. There are several posts on this forum about why this works and when.

We are searching for a solution of the following form $$\psi(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$$
When we plug in this solution into the wave equation we get:
$$a\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x} f(x)g(y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y} f(x)g(y)\right) + c f(x)g(y) = 0$$
Since $f(x)$ does not depend on $y$, and $g(y)$ does not depend on $x$, the above equation becomes:
$$ag(y)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x} f(x)+af(x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y}g(y)+ c f(x)g(y) = 0$$
Let's divide by $f(x)g(y)$ to obtain:
$$a\frac1{f(x)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x} f(x)+a\frac1{g(y)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y}g(y)+c=0$$
Notice that the first term depends only on $x$, the second only on $y$, the third is a constant, and they sum up to $0$. This can only happen only if the first two term are constant (independent of $x$ or $y$). So we write $$a\frac1{f(x)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x} f(x)=-c_1\\a\frac1{g(y)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y}g(y)=-c+c_1$$
We can replace partial derivatives with full derivatives now, since we have only one variable in each equation. Also, multiply the first equation by $f(x)$ and the second by $g(y)$. After re-arranging the terms you get
$$af''(x)+c_1f(x)=0\\ag''(y)+(c-c_1)g(y)=0$$
These are now simple 1D wave equations that you solve independently.

Answer (score 0):

Lets divide by $a$ everywhere
$$
\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial y^2} + \frac{c}{a}\psi = 0
$$
And lets call that constant $k^2=\frac{c}{a}$; the reason for squaring this constant is because I know it'll make things work out more nicely below.
$$
\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial y^2} + k^2\psi = 0
$$
Now apply the separation of variables, which is to look for solutions of the form $\psi(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$. Substituting that form, we have
$$
X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)Y''(y)+k^2X(x)Y(y)=0
$$
Divide through by $X(x)Y(y)$:
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}+k^2=0
$$
The usual argument is to say first term only depends on $x$, the second only on $y$, and the third is independent of both, and the three sum to something that is independent of both. It is sufficient for each term to be equal to a constant. Lets define then $\frac{X''}{X}=-k_x^2$, $\frac{Y''}{Y}=-k_y^2$, and then the equation is a constraint that reads
$$
k_x^2+k_y^2 = k^2,
$$
Again, choice of these constants as squares is because it makes things work out nicely without carrying around square roots everywhere. The constraint above means we can select any $k_x$ and $k_y$ values, so long as they are on a circle of radius $k$ (if $k$ is real; otherwise the constraint doesn't have this nice geometric interpretation, you'd have to think about circles with complex radii and what that means). The separated equations themselves, subject to that constraint, are
$$
X''+k_x^2X=0
$$
$$
Y''+k_y^2Y=0
$$
The general solutions are
$$
X(x) = C_{1x}\cos(k_xx)+C_{2x}\sin(k_xx)
$$
$$
Y(y) = C_{1y}\cos(k_yy)+C_{2y}\sin(k_yy)
$$
So now we have a general solution,
$$
\psi(x,y) = \left(C_{1x}\cos(k_xx)+C_{2x}\sin(k_xx)\right)\left(C_{1y}\cos(k_yy)+C_{2y}\sin(k_yy)\right)
$$
Rearranging and renaming the constants, we have
$$
\psi(x,y)=C_{1}\cos(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)+C_{2}\cos(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)+C_{3}\sin(k_xx)\cos(k_yy)+C_{4}\sin(k_xx)\sin(k_yy)
$$
Usually, now we'd apply boundary conditions, and that would exclude some of the above four terms. That would also restrict that valid wavenumbers to discrete integer multiples of some fundamental spatial frequency that is related to the size of the box. Then you'd write the most general solution as discrete summation over the valid wavenumbers. If you dont' have any of that, the most general solution is to integrate the above with respect to $k_x$ and $k_y$, realize the constants are functions $k_x$ and $k_y$, and the integral is subject to the constraint that $k_x^2+k_y^2=k^2$.